# How to Show that a Distribution is a Stationary Distribution for Metropolis-Hastings?

Tags: monte-carlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

For an Ising Model with a (2L+ 1) by (2L+ 1) square grid
of magnetic particles, show that $$\pi(\xi)=\frac{1}{Z_\beta}e^{\beta\sum_{x,y=x}{\xi_x\xi_y}}$$ Is indeed a stationary distribution for the Metropolis-Hasting process.  (Here $\beta > 0$ is
a constant, and $Z_\beta > 0$ is a too-hard-to-compute constant that makes $π$ an actual
distribution.) Recall the transition matrix for the process from Metropolis-Hasting
is $$p(\xi,\xi')=q(\xi,\xi')r(\xi,\xi')=q(\xi,\xi')min\Bigg(\frac{\pi(\xi')q(\xi',\xi)}{\pi(\xi)q(\xi,\xi')},1\Bigg)$$where our particular choice of distribution $q$ is $q(\xi,\xi')=(2L+1)^{-2}$ if $\xi$ and $\xi'$ have
only one magnetic particle with a different sign, and $q(\xi,\xi')=0$ otherwise

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Looks like a `self-study` tag is missing.

Answer (score 1):

**Typo:**
$$\pi(\xi)=\frac{1}{Z_\beta}e^{\beta\sum_{x,y=x}{\xi_x\xi_y}}$$
should be
$$\pi(\xi)=\frac{1}{Z_\beta}e^{\beta\sum_{x,y\sim x}{\xi_x\xi_y}}$$
where $x\sim y$ denotes the neighbourhood relation.

**Hint #1:** Is there anything special about the Ising when applying a Metropolis-Hastings (not Hasting) step?

**Hint #2:** What are the generic conditions for the Markov chain generated by a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm to converge?